# Lua programming ,error in establishing Database connection

Tags: lua, mysql-connect

After writing the code to connect to database,lua returns an error as

> Error in establishing connection to MySQL ,Can't connect to /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock

I'm unable to locate the /var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock file (which I haven't created )

My Sock is `/tmp/mysql.sock`

Below is my code to connect to MySQL database.

```
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"

local env  = mysql.mysql()
local conn = env:connect('test','root','')
print(env,conn)

status,errorString = conn:execute([[CREATE TABLE sample2 (id INTEGER, name TEXT);]])
print(status,errorString )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as seen there: [Luasql error: "LuaSQL: error connecting to database"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24424741/luasql-error-luasql-error-connecting-to-database), the problem is because luasql defaults to using a default socket path when connecting to localhost without a port. so just set the mysql host and port in `env:connect` or specify the socket path.

EDIT:
I believe your code should be:

```
env:connect('test','root','','localhost',3306) -- for tcp
-- or
env:connect('test','root','',':/tmp/mysql.sock') -- for socket
```

Comment: With LUA 5.2 on Ubuntu 14.04 I get an error "Unknown MySQL server host ':/tmp/mysql.sock'" for the socket version

Comment: well, does the socket exist in that path?

Comment: Yes, the socket I speciefied does exist, but I think not all versions of LuaSQL support the setting of the socket this way.