# Luasql error: "LuaSQL: error connecting to database"

Tags: mysql, database, lua

I am working on mysql. I am trying to acess the mysql database using the Luasql.I have installed Luasql using yum. Then i tried the following code:

```
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"

env = assert(mysql.mysql())

con = assert(env:connect ( "db_name", "username", "password", "localhost"))

for no, name in rows (con, "select * from t1") do

print (string.format ("%s", name))

end
```

While executing the above code i am getting the following error :

```
lua: check.lua:3: LuaSQL: error connecting to database. MySQL: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)
stack traceback:
    [C]: in function 'assert'
    check.lua:3: in main chunk
    [C]: ?
```

How to overcome this error.Can anyone help me for the proper execution of the code? Thanks !!!

Comment: Have you tried using your real `db_name`, `username` and `password` ?

Comment: @Egor I am getting the same error again.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the database using standard tools?

Comment: ya i am able to connect using standard tools..

Comment: Probably, you are using non-standard port?  Try `env:connect(..., "localhost", your_port)`

Comment: @Egor i am getting this error "  LuaSQL: error connecting to database. MySQL: Can't connect to MySQL server on '3306' (22)  "

Comment: Your error means you passed `3306` as hostname, not as port.  Your arguments for `connect` function seem to be shifted.  Are you sure you are using `env:connect(...)`, not `env.connect(...)` ?

Comment: @EgorSkriptunoff connection is established but now the error is in for loop which states " lua: check.lua:4: attempt to call global 'row' (a nil value) "

Comment: @Egor rows but its a variable only..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code executes well..thank u both @ EgorSkriptunoff &jaylzhang for ur responses

```
mysql = require "luasql.mysql"
env = assert(mysql.mysql())
con = assert(env:connect ( "db_name", "username", "password", "hostname", "3306"))
local cur = con:execute("select * from t1")
local row = cur:fetch({}, 'a')
for k, v in pairs(row) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Answer (score 1):

the variables in `env:connect` should be variables such as below

```
local db_conn = env:connect("test_db", "root", "abc123", "192.168.1.3", 3306)
local cur = db_conn:execute("select * from t1")
local row = cur:fetch({}, 'a')
for k, v in pairs(row) do
    print(k, v)
end
```

Comment: i am getting this error lua: check.lua:4: attempt to index local 'db_conn' (a nil value)
stack traceback:
 check.lua:4: in main chunk
 [C]: ?

Comment: uh, i think u know the basic example. your database name may be not 'test_db', your database host may be not '192.168.1.3', your name and password may be not 'root' and 'abc123', so u can't get an connect instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this. It will work with ZeroBraneIDE. Change the interpreter to lua instead of Lua 5.2 or 5.3.

You need to create System DSN on ODBC Data Sources from administrative tool, here it is "testDSN", as shown
[here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xnm7n.png):

```
require "luasql.odbc"
  env = assert(luasql.odbc())
  print(env)
  con = assert(env:connect("testDSN", "sa", "p@ssw0rd"))
  print(con)
  cur = assert (con:execute"use testdb")
  cur = assert (con:execute"SELECT MSISD FROM MSID")
  row = cur:fetch({}, "a")

  while row do
    print(string.format("%s",row.MSISD))
    row = cur:fetch (row, "a")
  end

  cur:close()
  con:close()
  env:close()
```